# RadGridView multiselecting by mouseclick without ctrl button

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

Is it possible to multiselecting rows by click on row?

I mean that I want to the radgridview after left click on row behave like click with ctrl.

Answer (score -1):

From [Telerik's page on Multiple Selection](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/gridview-multiple-selection.html):

The RadGridView allows the user to select more than one item from the displayed data. By default this functionality is disabled and to turn it on you have to set the SelectionMode property to either Multiple or Extended.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView"
                             SelectionMode="Extended">
    ...
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

You can also set this server-side in your C# code:

```
this.radGridView.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Controls.SelectionMode.Extended;
```

Comment: This isn't my problem. I have selectionmode on Extended and now when I click somewhere on row it change selection on only this row. When I click somewhere on row with ctrl button pressed it add selection on this row and other wgich earlier was selected still are selected.

I want to do this second situation without ctrl button pressed instead first situation.